# Unit / Integration testing a tk application

Tags: unit-testing, tcl, integration-testing, tk-toolkit

I am trying to find any suitable software preferably open source to do tdd and bdd testing in a tk application.

If you have any suggestion, I would be very grateful.

Regards,
Panos

Answer (score 0):

Tcl includes the [tcltest](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/tcltest.htm) package.  Since you are using Tcl/Tk, it should work out well.

There are many testing frameworks available, but I don't know which are popular (which means easier to find a support community) and usable.